# Definable non measurable set after adding one Cohen real to L

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $x$ is a Cohen real over the constructible universe $L$. Is there a (parameter free) definable non measurable set of reals in $L[x]$?

This appeared in Will Brian's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273861/independence-over-zfc-ch/279048#279048) where he noted that the analogous question after adding a random real has a postive answer.

Comment: It's known that if there is a set of reals $X$ of size $\aleph_1$ then there is a non-measurable set $Y$. I haven't checked the details (I can't access the relevant paper right now), but I think that if $X$ is definable without parameters, then so is $Y$. If that's correct, then the fact that $|\mathbb{R}^L|=\aleph_1^{L[x]}$ should imply the existence of the required non-measurable set.

Answer (score 10):

The paper "[$\Delta^1_2$-sets of reals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800728990016X?via%3Dihub)" by Ihoda (=Judah) and Shelah  [Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 42 (1989) 207-223] should have the result you want.

Theorem 3.1(i) tells you that every $\Delta^1_2(r_0)$ ($\Delta^1_2$ using only $r_0$ as a parameter) set is Lebesgue measurable if and only if there is a real $r$ that is random over $L[r_0]$.

In particular, all $\Delta^1_2$ (parameter free) sets of reals are measurable if and only if there is a random real over $L$.  This latter fails if we add a single Cohen real to $L$, so there is a non-measurable $\Delta^1_2$ (without parameters) set in $L[c]$ if $c$ is Cohen over $L$.

The paper addresses regularity properties of $\Delta^1_2$ sets in many different settings, and not just Lebesgue measurability.